# Can't create project on Netbeans 12 with JDK 17

Tags: java, netbeans, java-17, netbeans-12

My professor wants us to download NetBeans and a JDK. The problem is that although I can install them both, I cant create a project:

[image: Project Wizard]

I have tried to open other files as shown below, but they don't run:

[image: EditScreen]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Netbeans, but are you sure it isn't running? What happens if you click on the `output` icon?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are running NetBeans 12.0 with JDK 17. That is not a supported combination. From [the release notes for NetBeans 12.0](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb120/nb120.html):

> Apache NetBeans 12.0 runs on the JDK LTS releases 8 and 11, as well as
> on JDK 14, i.e., the current JDK release at the time of this NetBeans
> release.

Either install and use a supported JDK with NetBeans 12.0, or install and use NetBeans 12.6 with JDK 17.